# can't find plaint text in android

Tags: android

While learning how to build a simple user interface on The instructs. From the Palette window on the left, click Text in the left panel, and then drag Plain Text into the design editor and drop it near the top of the layout.  Where exactly can I find "plain-text", or is it something I type then drag into the design editor?

The link's down below:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#textbox

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio 2.3.3, click on Text in the Palette, and Plain Text will be one of the options:

[image: Android Studio Palette]

Answer (score 0):

You can find it here.
Start typing after pressing the magnifying button it would show up as the top result.

[image]